# Granting Runtime Permission for a thirdparty app

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to grant the Permission `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES` to an Android App, which is not made by me. My Device is running on LineageOS and is rooted, but the Command

```
pm grant <package> android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
```

returns

```
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES is not a changeable permission type.
```

Is there any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution: Copying the app to the /system/app folder through TWRP works fine